# How to plot an igraph object on a vector map in R

Tags: r, plot, graph, igraph

I use the `igraph` and `sf` packages.

I have an igraph object whose vertices have spatial coordinates `geo_dist_graph`.
The vertices names and coordinates look like this:

```r
grid_grid <- 
structure(list(coords.x1 = c(15.504078, 15.704078, 15.904078, 
15.104078, 15.304078, 15.504078, 15.704078, 15.104078, 15.304078, 
15.704078, 14.904078, 14.304078, 13.904078, 14.704078, 13.704078, 
14.104078, 14.704078, 14.904078, 13.704078, 13.904078, 14.704078, 
13.704078, 13.904078, 14.304078), 
coords.x2 = c(43.835623, 43.835623, 
43.835623, 44.035623, 44.035623, 44.035623, 44.035623, 44.235623, 
44.235623, 44.235623, 44.435623, 44.635623, 44.835623, 44.835623, 
45.035623, 45.035623, 45.035623, 45.035623, 45.235623, 45.235623, 
45.235623, 45.435623, 45.435623, 45.435623), 
g9.nodes = c(27, 
28, 29, 40, 41, 42, 43, 55, 56, 58, 69, 81, 94, 98, 108, 110, 
113, 114, 123, 124, 128, 138, 139, 141)), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", 
"14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23", "24"
))
```

The graph is from a simple squared adjacency matrix:

```r
geo_dist_graph <- 
  structure(c(NA, 1, 1, NA, NA, 1, 1, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, NA, 1, NA, NA, NA, 
1, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, 1, 1, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, NA, 
NA, 1, 1, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, NA, 1, NA, NA, 1, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, NA, NA, NA, 1, NA, 
1, NA, 1, 1, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, 1, 1, 1, NA, NA, 1, NA, NA, NA, 1, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, 1, NA, 1, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, 1, 1, NA, 1, NA, 1, 1, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, 1, NA, 
1, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, 1, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, 1, NA, 1, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, NA, NA, 1, 1, 
NA, NA, NA, 1, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, 1, 1, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, 1, NA, NA, 1, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, NA, NA, 1, NA, 
NA, 1, 1, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, 1, 1, NA, 1, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, NA, NA, NA, 1, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, NA, NA, NA, 1, 
NA, NA, 1, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, 1, NA, NA, 1, NA, NA, NA, 1, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, 1, NA, 1, 1, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, 1, NA, 1, 1, NA, NA, 1, NA, NA, 1, 1, 1, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, NA, NA, 1, 1, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, 1, NA, NA, 1, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, 
1, NA, 1, NA, 1, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, NA, NA, NA, 1, NA, NA, 1, NA), 
.Dim = c(24L, 
24L))

colnames(geo_dist_graph) <- grid_grid$g9.nodes
row.names(geo_dist_graph) <- grid_grid$g9.nodes

geo_dist_graph <- graph_from_adjacency_matrix(geo_dist_graph, mode = "upper", diag = F)
```

The spatial coordinates where attched this way:

```
V(geo_dist_graph)$x <- 
  grid_grid$coords.x1[match(V(geo_dist_graph)$name, grid_grid$g9.nodes)]

V(geo_dist_graph)$y <- 
  grid_grid$coords.x2[match(V(geo_dist_graph)$name, grid_grid$g9.nodes)]
```

The graph is correclty plotted in space when using the `plot` function. But when I try to add a basemap like this `plot(map_crop_sp, add = T)`, the map doesn't show behind the graph, but there is no error message.

The map is vector map, don't know if it's important. Here is the code used to create it.

```
map <- st_read("ne_10m_coastline/ne_10m_coastline.shp")
map_crop <- st_crop(map, xmin = 13.304078, ymin = 43.635623, xmax = 16.503846, ymax = 45.60185)
map_crop_sp <- as(map_crop, Class = "Spatial")
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow. Can you provide a [minimal, reproducible set](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5963610/5805670), i.e. some small dataset and accompanying code so that others can reproduce this problem? If you cannot share your data, try generating some arbitrary data that looks like your real data. Because right now, the problem may arise due to a multitude of reasons.

Comment: Hi, thanks for you comments, I added some data and code. I hope this helps.

Comment: Hi, I reformatted the data a bit (with `dput`) so that it's easier to copy for others. Also, when I run `st_read("ne_10m_coastline/ne_10m_coastline.shp")`, it says the file doesn't exist, so I presume you downloaded it from somewhere?

Comment: Thanks! yeah, from https://www.naturalearthdata.com/downloads/10m-physical-vectors/.  I can also attach the file but I don't know how to do it.

Comment: Ok, perfect. Sorry, last problem. It seems that `geo_dist_graph` is an `igraph` object, but I'm having trouble converting the matrix to `igraph`. In particular, I'm not sure what `g9.nodes` is in your code. Can you maybe run `dput(geo_dist_graph)` on your data and replace it in the opening post?

Comment: It's my fault, my code is a mess. I edited the post, normally the code should work this way

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Answer**

Since the `igraph` should be on top of the map, I plot it second. I also added `rescale = F`:

```r
plot(map_crop_sp)
plot(geo_dist_graph, add = T, rescale = F)
```

[image]

**Rationale**

I typed `?plot.igraph`. From there, I found `?igraph.plotting`. It seems that plotting an `igraph` object rescales it (`plot(..., rescale = TRUE)`:

> Logical constant, whether to rescale the coordinates to the [-1,1]x-1,1 interval. This parameter is not implemented for tkplot.
>
> Defaults to TRUE, the layout will be rescaled.